# Redux: passing information to/from window child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Essentially I am trying to create an app where it has a note-pad feature that opens up a window child and passes some information from the parent (which holds the redux state) to it.

However, I am having trouble on how to send the information from the child to the parent, specifically dealing with dispatching action.

I was able to figure it out on passing from parent to child as so without using Redux:

**Parent Window**

```
class NavBar extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.handleNotesMenu = this.handleNotesMenu.bind(this)
    }

handleNotesMenu() {
    window.id = this.props.id
    window.userName = this.props.userName
    window.currentReduxState = store.getState()
    const notePad = window.open('NotePad', 'notes', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=715,height=325')
}
```

**Child Window**

```
export class NotePad extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            notes: window.opener.state.getIn(['plan', 'notes'])
        }
    }


    handleChange(tabID) {
        return e => {
            const state = {}
            state[tabID] = e.target.value
            this.setState(state)
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
                 <textarea 
                    id="saveArea" 
                    value={this.state.notes}
                    onChange={this.handleChange('notes')}
                    name="textarea" 
                />
        )
    }
}
```

I thought out about that adding action dispatcher to the child was hard, so I was thinking somehow incorporate with **sessionStorage**. But then I got stumped on how the **parent window** is able to listen to listenStorage on the fly.

Any thoughts? What would be the best practice when it comes to dealing with window child in React/Redux?

Comment: I don't think a browser-window/popup instance should be used as a component rendered from inside the parent since it's not really part of the same DOM. You don't show whether `NavBar` has a `render()` method or not. In any case a render method is required for all react components.

Answer (score 0):

Send a method as prop which will take the returning data as argument from child component and call this method in your childcomponent with that data...like this....
In parent component.....

```
someMethod(data){
      // do something here with data
  }
```

In your render method pass this method to child component as...

```
<ChildComponent someMethod={this.someMethod}  />
```

Now in your child component call that method like this...

```
this.props.someMethod(someData);
```

And that's it your are done...
You have passed the data your parent component without dispatch ... In that someMethod() you can do whatever you wanna do with that data